# Should the "Featured" Tab be Removed from MetaSO?

Tags: discussion, bountied-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the use of the Featured question tab in Meta, if there are no bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/whats-the-use-of-the-featured-question-tab-in-meta-if-there-are-no-bounties)

No bounties means no featured items?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/whats-the-use-of-the-featured-question-tab-in-meta-if-there-are-no-bounties

Comment: Oops...Dupe           .

Comment: @JonathanSampson Seems this question links to a deleted one. Maybe reopen it? Or redirect it to an existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no bounties and never going to *be* any bounties then it would make sense for it to not be there... on the other hand, if removing it is going to take time away from other features, I don't think it's actually doing significant harm.

Also, I wouldn't be surprised to see bounties taking on some meaning on Meta eventually. I've suggested before that it might be a way of a user (or collection of users, if eventually bounties can be contributed by onlookers) expressing a really high level of desire for a feature.

Answer (score -1):

If there are no bounties, then yeah.